# How do I find files with no group permissions?

Tags: command-line, permissions, find, groups

I just want to know how I can find, in a folder, the files  that have no group user permission (no read/write/execute) at all, using the terminal.

Answer (score 20):

You can use:

```
find . \! -perm /070
```

Or:

```
find . \! -perm /g+rwx
```

This works because:

- When the operand of the `-perm` test starts with `/`, it causes `-perm` to test if *any* of the specified permissions are present.

  (If you used `-` in place of `/`, it would test if *all* were present. Without a prefix character, it would test for *exactly* the permission specified, i.e., all of them *and no others* present.)
- That's the opposite of what you're looking for -- *none* is the opposite of *any* -- and the *not* operator `\!` negates the result of the test that follows it.

  (The operator is really `!`, and you can probably write it that way, but it's commonly written as `\!` to ensure that one's shell passes it on to `find` rather than treating it specially.)

As for the meaning of the specific strings after `/`, see [FilePermissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions), [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)), and/or [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chmod.1.html). In summary, as applied to the commands shown above:

- `070` is an octal permissions string, specifying permissions for user (i.e., owner), group, and other (i.e., everyone else), respectively. 7 is read (4), write (2), and execute (1) permissions (i.e., `111` has the `1` bits in `100`, `010`, and `001`).
- `g+rwx` is a symbolic permissions string, specifying that the group (`g`) has read (`r`), write (`w`), and execute (`x`) permissions.

Whichever notation you use, remember that you're expressing the opposite of what you ultimately want, since the result of the test is negated by `!`.

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate it! I wasn’t aware of the ‘ / ‘ I was using ‘-‘ instead.

Answer (score 6):

To find any file in the current directory or its subdirectories for which none group read, write or execute bits are set, run:

```
find . ! -perm /g+rwx
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

With easy commands from your private terminal run:

```bash
sudo df --local -P | awk {'if (NR!=1) print $6'} | xargs -I '{}' find '{}' -xdev -nogroup -ls
```

Comment: why 0 point the line is correct sickness _))_